# optimize ram intellij for java microservice project

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, microservices

I am having a java microservice project using Spring Boot and develop in IntelliJ. I have more than 10 services but i just have only 15GB ram on my laptop. I need to run 10 services in IntelliJ IDE so I want to optimize memory usage for these services. How can I limit the memory usage of each service or limit memory for all services. Somebody can help me or give a solution for that. change maximum heap size is 750mb. This setting for each service or all of service. somebody can explain this to me. Sorry about my grammar and thank you for reading my question.
[image]

Comment: If you edit the run configuration of each of these services, you can set `-Xmx` for JVM. You might have to do it for each of them separately though. Which JDK are you using?

Comment: i use jdk8 for my project @aksappy

Answer (score 1):

One option is to go to each service's run configuration in IntelliJ
and update `Xmx` in VM options. Something like the screenshot below.

[image]